# How to let Matlab show solutions directly without assignment

Tags: matlab

Say I want to solve a simple system of equations in Matlab:

```
syms a b
eqns=[a+b==4,a-b==2];
vars=[a,b];
solve(eqns,vars)
```

The result is just annoying:

```
ans = 

  struct with fields:

    a: [1×1 sym]
    b: [1×1 sym]
```

I just want Matlab to display the values of the variables. Is there a way to see the solutions without using

```
[asol,bsol]=solve(eqns,vars)
```

I can also use `s=solve(eqns,vars)`, but then I have to type `s.b` and `s.b` to see the result. I just want to see the result directly.

Comment: Why do you want to directly show the solutions? I think `s.a` and `s.b` are pretty straightforward. Is that because you have a large number of unknown variables. For example, a1, a2, ..., a100?

Comment: @BanghuaZhao Exactly, I have alot of unknowns. Is there a way to use for loop to hanle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, you want a way to loop through the result `s` (`s=solve(eqns,vars)`) to show all solutions.

In this case, `s` is a [struct](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html). This is a question of iterating through struct field. You can use [`fieldnames`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fieldnames.html) function returns a cell array of fields names (in this case, variable names in the equations):

```
syms a b
eqns=[a+b==4,a-b==2];
vars=[a,b];
s = solve(eqns,vars)

fields = fieldnames(s);

for i = 1:numel(fields)
  s.(fields{i})
end
```

Output:

```
ans =

3


ans =

1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap `structfun` around `solve(eqns,vars)` it will run over all fields of the structure and apply a function. Thus using the function `f=@(x) x` it will just print the solution.

```
structfun(@(x) x, solve(eqns,vars))
```

Comment: I got "Error using structfun
sym output type is not supported. Set 'UniformOutput' to false."

Comment: Well, for the example it runs for me on 2018b. Are you using it on something else? Or which version do you have?

Comment: I used 2017a version. But I also have 2018b in another laptop and it worked! However, if I have fewer equations than variables and I run structfun(@(x) x, solve(eqns,vars, 'ReturnConditions', true)), then I got "Error using structfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 3, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false."

Comment: Have you tried setting ‘UniformOutput’ to false? As the error suggests?